# Appending fields with jquery in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to make a button '+' to allow to the user add more address fields with JQuery but in 'zf2' after i submit the form it back to the form with validation message but with out the fields added 'Appending' with JQuery.

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe show us some code.
Otherwise (I don't know if you do like this) you can use an address fieldset to add dynamically address fields.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Comment: I want to get the view of the form after post

This is the code show the form:
return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
But before post the use have option to add new input field so how can i recieve the new html form structure with new fields ?